# Objectify: Datastore small operations for count queries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

As per Google Documentation

```
Small datastore operations include calls to allocate datastore ids or keys-only queries, and these operations are free.
```

If following query return 10,000; will that be 'one small operation' or '10,000 read operations'

```
int count = ofy().load().type(Employee.class).filter("location", "US").keys().list().size();
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Comment: @PaulCollingwood just added appstats, it is taking 10K read calls.

Comment: Appstats pricing is off https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11397 One way to check if it costing you is to check your Quotas page, run the code and see if the number of reads or small ops increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will cost 1 read operation for the query and 10,000 small operations for the results.

It will be more memory efficient (although no different in terms of datastore operations) to execute this:

```
int count = ofy().load().type(Employee.class).filter("location", "US").count();
```

Comment: Hello, @stickfigure Why there is one read operation, May I know?

Comment: There is always 1 read op for a query. (unless they changed something recently, of course)